# string.contains and string.replace in one single line of code

Tags: c#, linq, parsing

I'm currently writing some software where I have to load a lot of columnnames from an external file. Usually I would do this with some JSON but for reasons of userfriendlyness I can't do it right now. I need to use a textfile which is readable to the users and includes a lot of comments.

So I have created my own file to hold all of these values.

Now when I'm importing these values in my software I essentially run through my configfile line by line and I check for every line if it matches a parameter which I then parse. But this way I end up with a big codeblock with very repetitive code and I was wondering is could not simplify it in a way so that every check is done in just one line.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
if (line.Contains("[myValue]"))
{
   myParameter = line.Replace("[myValue]", string.Empty).Trim();                        
}
```

I know that using Linq you can simply things and put them in one single line, I'm just not sure if it would work in this case?

Thanks for your help!
Kenneth

Comment: Your code doesn't look very repetitive to me. It only has two lines of actual code. Do you think you could edit the code so that we can understand where the repetition is?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir - There is no `myParameter`. Where are you getting that from?

Comment: @Enigmativity Are we looking at the same question? `myParameter = line.Replace.....`

Comment: There’s no need for contains check, replace will only replace it when it exists

Comment: @john - Sorry, my mistake. I wasn't looking at the start of the line.

Comment: To clarify: myParameter is set at the beginning of the codeblock and defaults to a string.Empty. If the line doesn't compile I don't want set the value of myParameter, so you are correct @mjwills. The repetition lies in the fact that I have about 50 parameters that I need to get out of the external file. So I have the same if-block 50 times to check for each of the 50 parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just create a method if this piece of code often repeated :

```
void SetParameter(string line, string name, ref string parameter)
{
    if (line.Contains(name))
    {
       parameter = line.Replace(name, string.Empty).Trim();                        
    }
}
SetParameter(line, "[myValue]", ref myParameter);
```

If you want to avoid calling both `Replace` and `Contains`, which is probably a good idea, you could also just call `Replace`:

```
void SetParameter(string line, string name, ref string parameter)
{
    var replaced = line.Replace(name, string.Empty);
    if (line != replaced)
    {
       parameter = replaced.Trim();                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (ternary):

```
myParameter = line.Contains("[myValue]")?line.Replace("[myValue]", string.Empty).Trim():myParameter;
```

Actually,

`line.IndexOf` should be faster.

From your code, look like you are replacing with just empty text, so why not take the entire string (consisting of many lines) and replace at one shot, instead of checking one line at a time.

Comment: @Sunil replace `line` at the end of your solution by `myParameter`

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegEx. This might possibly relieve you of some repetitive code

```
        string line = "[myvalue1] some string [someotherstring] [myvalue2]";
        // All your Keys stored at a single place
        string[] keylist = new string[] {  @"\[myvalue1]", @"\[myvalue2]" };

        var newString = Regex.Replace(line, string.Join("|", keylist), string.Empty);
```

Hope it helps.